# In Java: What happens if I change a key in an HashMap to be equal to another key?

Tags: java, hashmap, equals

I know that I can not have 2 keys in a HashMap which are equal (by the equals()-method). And if I try to add a key-value-pair to the HashMap with the key already existing, the old value is just replaced by the new one.

But what if I change an already existing key to be equal to another existing key?

How will the map.get() method behave in this case (applied to one of these equal keys)?

Very simple example below.

```
public class Person{
  private int age;
  private String name;

  public Person(int a, String n){
    age = a;
    name = n;
  }

  public void setAge(int a){ age = a; }
  public int getAge(){return age; }
  public String getName() {return name; }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o){
     if(!(o instanceof Person)){return false;}
     Person p = (Person) o;
     return ((p.getName().equals(this.getName())) && (p.getAge() == this.getAge()));
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode(){return age;}
}

public class MainClass{
 public static void main(String[]args){
   Person p1 = new Person("Bill", 20);
   Person p2 = new Person("Bill", 21); 
   HashMap<Person, String> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put(p1, "some value");
   map.put(p2, "another value");
   p1.setAge(21);
   String x = map.get(p1); // <-- What will this be??
   System.out.println(x);  
 }

}
```

Comment: Override value!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you mutate a key which is already present in the `HashMap` you break the `HashMap`. You are not supposed to mutate keys present in the `HashMap`. If you must mutate such keys, you should remove them from the `HashMap` before the change, and `put` them again in the `HashMap` after the change.

`map.get(p1)` will search for the key `p1` according to its new `hashCode`, which is equal to the hash code of `p2`. Therefore it will search in the bucket that contains `p2`, and return the corresponding value - `"another value"` (unless both keys happen to be mapped to the same bucket, in which case either value can be returned, depending on which key would be tested first for equality).

Comment: this `you break the HashMap` it a bit misleading, you don't break anything inside the `HashMap` - you are breaking some operations related to that particular key (i.e. search will not work). When an `Entry` is created values are copied into the new Object - I assume you know that and slightly made your answer misleading.

Answer (score 2):

In short: p1 will not be reachable anymore.

In general the map is using the hash function to split the keys to buckets and then the equal function to locate the correct key-value. when you change the value of `p1` and with that its hash value. If you will look for it the map will look for the value in a different bucket and will not see it and the `p1` that is in the map will not be reachable.